# Unity3d detect the click on a plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click

I'm trying to detect when the user click on a plane in C#. I tryed `OnMouseDown()` but it has no effect.

According to some topics on the web, the object must have a collider, but my plane has one.

I also found topics talking about raycast, but I must admit I don't really understand what it is and what it does. Could someone lead me to a good and (relatively) simple exemple that explains well how to do what I would like to do?

Thanks, have a good day

Comment: Is the plane marked as Trigger? "_This function is called on Colliders marked as Trigger if and only if Physics.queriesHitTriggers is true._" from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: Pffffft.... Why the hell don't I pay attention to everything I read... sorry for this question I should've solved myself, have a good, day, this was the answser!

Comment: Ahahaha, it could happen to miss this one! You're welcome, I've added an answer too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my previous comment, the plane was marked as `Trigger`.

"*This function is called on Colliders marked as Trigger if and only if Physics.queriesHitTriggers is true.*" from [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.h%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btml).